# Plotting on charts js more than one dataset

Tags: javascript, json, charts

I have the following json:

```
[
{"periodo":"0","mes":"7","anio":"2015","montoIngreso":0,"monedaIngreso":"0","identifierIngreso":null,"montoGasto":0,"monedaGasto":"0","identifierGasto":null,"balance":0",
{"periodo":"1","mes":"8","anio":"2015","montoIngreso":0,"monedaIngreso":"0","identifierIngreso":null,"montoGasto":0,"monedaGasto":"0","identifierGasto":null,"balance":0},
{"periodo":"2","mes":"9","anio":"2015","montoIngreso":0,"monedaIngreso":"0","identifierIngreso":null,"montoGasto":0,"monedaGasto":"0","identifierGasto":null,"balance":0},
{"periodo":"3","mes":"10","anio":"2015","montoIngreso":0,"monedaIngreso":"0","identifierIngreso":null,"montoGasto":0,"monedaGasto":"0","identifierGasto":null,"balance":0},
{"periodo":"4","mes":"11","anio":"2015","montoIngreso":0,"monedaIngreso":"0","identifierIngreso":null,"montoGasto":0,"monedaGasto":"0","identifierGasto":null,"balance":0},
{"periodo":"5","mes":"12","anio":"2015","montoIngreso":0,"monedaIngreso":"0","identifierIngreso":null,"montoGasto":0,"monedaGasto":"0","identifierGasto":null,"balance":0},
{"periodo":"6","mes":"1","anio":"2016","montoIngreso":0,"monedaIngreso":"0","identifierIngreso":null,"montoGasto":0,"monedaGasto":"0","identifierGasto":null,"balance":0},
{"periodo":"7","mes":"2","anio":"2016","montoIngreso":0,"monedaIngreso":"0","identifierIngreso":null,"montoGasto":0,"monedaGasto":"0","identifierGasto":null,"balance":0},
{"periodo":"8","mes":"3","anio":"2016","montoIngreso":0,"monedaIngreso":"0","identifierIngreso":null,"montoGasto":0,"monedaGasto":"0","identifierGasto":null,"balance":0},
{"periodo":"9","mes":"4","anio":"2016","montoIngreso":0,"monedaIngreso":"0","identifierIngreso":null,"montoGasto":0,"monedaGasto":"0","identifierGasto":null,"balance":0},
{"periodo":"10","mes":"5","anio":"2016","montoIngreso":0,"monedaIngreso":"0","identifierIngreso":null,"montoGasto":0,"monedaGasto":"0","identifierGasto":null,"balance":0},
{"periodo":"11","mes":"6","anio":"2016","montoIngreso":3833.874,"monedaIngreso":"1","identifierIngreso":"ARS","montoGasto":175.56,"monedaGasto":"1","identifierGasto":"ARS","balance":3658.314},
{"periodo":"11","mes":"6","anio":"2016","montoIngreso":3833.874,"monedaIngreso":"1","identifierIngreso":"ARS","montoGasto":"460810","monedaGasto":"2","identifierGasto":"USD","balance":-456976.126},
{"periodo":"11","mes":"6","anio":"2016","montoIngreso":3833.874,"monedaIngreso":"1","identifierIngreso":"ARS","montoGasto":190.4448,"monedaGasto":"3","identifierGasto":"UYU","balance":3643.4292},
{"periodo":"11","mes":"6","anio":"2016","montoIngreso":"5000","monedaIngreso":"2","identifierIngreso":"USD","montoGasto":175.56,"monedaGasto":"1","identifierGasto":"ARS","balance":4824.44},
{"periodo":"11","mes":"6","anio":"2016","montoIngreso":"5000","monedaIngreso":"2","identifierIngreso":"USD","montoGasto":"460810","monedaGasto":"2","identifierGasto":"USD","balance":-455810},
{"periodo":"11","mes":"6","anio":"2016","montoIngreso":"5000","monedaIngreso":"2","identifierIngreso":"USD","montoGasto":190.4448,"monedaGasto":"3","identifierGasto":"UYU","balance":4809.5552},
{"periodo":"12","mes":"7","anio":"2016","montoIngreso":219.318,"monedaIngreso":"1","identifierIngreso":"ARS","montoGasto":15.444,"monedaGasto":"1","identifierGasto":"ARS","balance":203.874},
{"periodo":"12","mes":"7","anio":"2016","montoIngreso":219.318,"monedaIngreso":"1","identifierIngreso":"ARS","montoGasto":"105002","monedaGasto":"2","identifierGasto":"USD","balance":-104782.682},
{"periodo":"12","mes":"7","anio":"2016","montoIngreso":"324342","monedaIngreso":"2","identifierIngreso":"USD","montoGasto":15.444,"monedaGasto":"1","identifierGasto":"ARS","balance":324326.556},
{"periodo":"12","mes":"7","anio":"2016","montoIngreso":"324342","monedaIngreso":"2","identifierIngreso":"USD","montoGasto":"105002","monedaGasto":"2","identifierGasto":"USD","balance":219340}]
```

And i have a var with the labels:

```
["2015-7", "2015-8", "2015-9", "2015-10", "2015-11", "2015-12", "2016-1", "2016-2", "2016-3", "2016-4", "2016-5", "2016-6", "2016-7"]
```

From the first json, there supposed to be three datasets "montoIngreso" "montoGasto" and "balance"

The problem is that for some of the labels, i have two values on the json, for instance

anio:2016 mes:7 have 4 records so i need to add each of them to form 3 unique datasets

how can i do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok its not fancy but:

```
var valoresIngresos = new Array(labels.length).fill(0);
var valoresGastos = new Array(labels.length).fill(0);
var valoresBalance = new Array(labels.length).fill(0);


for(var i=0;i<labels.length;i++) {

    var fuentes = dataSource.filter(source=>(source.anio+"-"+source.mes) == labels[i]);
    for(var j=0;j<fuentes.length;j++) {

    valoresIngresos[i] = valoresIngresos[i]+parseFloat(fuentes[j].montoIngreso);
    valoresGastos[i] = valoresGastos[i]+parseFloat(fuentes[j].montoGasto);
    valoresBalance[i] = valoresBalance[i]+parseFloat(fuentes[j].balance);
    }

    }

var ingresosDataset = { 
        label: "Ingresos",
        data:valoresIngresos,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.31)",
        borderColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
        pointBorderColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
        pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointBorderWidth: 1,
    };

    datasets.push(ingresosDataset);
```